# How I can get min column value in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have table

| ID | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |

I want to select the minimum number for each ID without deleting duplicates

| ID | number | min_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 5 |

How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on a RDBMS that supports modern SQL then you just need to add

```
MIN(number) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS min_number
```

to your SELECT list